Multiselect of Primvue becomes null data when the data is passed to v-model
      <MultiSelect id="Color-input"
        v-model="DesignData.ColorQty"
        options="DesignColors"
        optionLabel="colorName"
        label="Color" />

Data-
        data() {
          return {
            DesignData: [ColorQty[]],
            DesignColors: [ {
                colorName: "Red",
                sizes: { A: 0, B: 0, C: 0, D: 0, E: 0 },
                hexCode: "#FF0000",
            },
            {
                colorName: "Blue",
                sizes: { A: 0, B: 0, C: 0, D: 0, E: 0 },
                hexCode: "#0000FF",
            },
            {
                colorName: "Green",
                sizes: { A: 0, B: 0, C: 0, D: 0, E: 0 },
                hexCode: "#00FF00",
            },
            {
                colorName: "Black",
                sizes: { A: 0, B: 0, C: 0, D: 0, E: 0 },
                hexCode: "#000000",
            },],
            },
          }
        }

When I set -
this.DesignData.ColorQty = [ {
                "colorName": "Black"
                "sizes": { "A": 3, "B": 4, "C": 5, "D": 5, "E": 5 },
                "hexCode": "#000000",
            }]

used import and components for Multiselect component
the option in multiselect was showing null instead of showing black
if I set the values of all sizes as 0 then it is working. I don't get what is causing the issue.

It's unclear how it's supposed to work. What is this.DesignData.ColorQty = supposed to do in your opinion? Selected options and all options should be two different arrays, this isn't so in your case

I honestly could not understand your question very well, but here's a few thoughts on the code you provided:

You need to bind the MultiSelect options to a variable, such as :options="DesignColors" (with a colon). Without the colon, you're assigning the options to be the value of the string 'DesignColors'.

Is DesignColors simply an empty array? A bit more context code would be helpful.

You seem to be missing a comma after "colorName": "Black" in your last code snippet.



Your v-model should be an array instead of vue object. The options should be :options="DesignData.ColorQty".

I'm unfamiliar with PrimeVue, but I don't think you can use objects in your v-model I think you need to use the colorName instead as the selectedColors, and the options="DesignColors" should be: :options="DesignData.ColorQty".
So your v-model should be an array of selectedColornames and the options should be :options="DesignData.ColorQty"
